# Conditional mapping list entries in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Good morning. I need to update the mapping of items in an order based on the item(s) being "invoiced". Currently, there is no conditional mapping of order items. I've been looking at conditional and preconditional mapping in Automapper, but I'm not sure how to do this for a List of items.

Here's what it looks like currently.

```
     CreateMap<OrderDto, Order>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TransactionId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => CreateTransactionId(src.OrderHeader)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TransactionType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => MapTransactionType(src.OrderHeader.OrderType)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderLine ) )
            .ReverseMap();
        
        CreateMap<OrderLineDto, OrderItem>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LineNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LineNumber))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Upc, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Item.Upc))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Sku, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Item.Upc))
            .ReverseMap();
```

So, the logic I need to add is to only map OrderLines that have an entry in the orderLines.quantity(list).type='Invoiced'. I'm sure this is probably a simple process, I just couldn't find an example. Thank you for recommendations!

Comment: `opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderLine.Where(ol => ol. Type="Invoiced") )`?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` to filter the type to be "Invoiced" by:

```cs
 .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderLine.Where(t => t.Quantity.FirstOrDefault().Type == "Invoiced")))
```

Comment: Thank you, Misha, for your response. I just noticed that the Type property is in a Quantity list. So, it's like this. 

orderLine.quantity.type == "Invoiced".

So, I need to find an "invoiced" type within the Quantity list. I tried the following, but it doesn't like it. Thanks again!

.ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderLine.Where(t => t.Quantity.FirstOrDefault().Type == "Invoiced") ) )

Comment: @ChrisP Cool, I updated my answer accordingly. Glad it helped.
Please approve this answer :)